# ¿Qué artículo se debe usar para un sustantivo femenino que empieza en "a" tónica cuando es implícito?

Tags: género, artículos

En la frase:

> El agua del río Danubio es muy sucia; **la** del río Tara, en cambio, es cristalina.

Es correcto el uso del artículo femenino "la" para referirse al sustantivo implícito "agua", o se debería decir "el del río Tara"?

Tiene sentido usar "la" pues ya no hay repetición de la sílaba "a", pero me parece extraño cambiar el género del artículo entre la primera y segunda oración si se refieren al mismo sustantivo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El artículo siempre acompaña al nombre, por lo tanto en plural es *las aguas*, y en singular como termina por *a* y empieza el nombre por *A* es *el agua*, aunque *agua* sigue siendo femenina.

En tu ejemplo tienes mal el planteamiento ya que el artículo NUNCA puede sustituir al nombre, NUNCA, siempre lo acompaña. Por lo tanto, *la* no es artículo sino pronombre, porque sustituye al nombre (*agua*).

Ahora, volviendo a tu pregunta, se dice *la* porque el nombre es femenino y ya no hay problema fonético, por lo tanto la concordancia prevalece.